# constantly check iframe if url has been changed from inside via Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is this possible?

Comment: is the address of the iframe local or external in regards to domains, such as your trying to manipulate google.com or your own site ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have just one iframe...

```
$("iframe").load(function() {
  alert("Changed!");
  alert(frames[0].document.body.innerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

yh this works:

1_

```
 <iframe src ="page.html" name="fraFrame" id="fraFrame" onLoad="alert('url changed!!!');"> 
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes :P</p>
 </iframe>
```

2_
using DOM reference or jquery thing:

```
$("#fraFrame").load(function (){
    // do something once the iframe is loaded
});
```

Comment: $("#fraFrame").load(function (){
    // do something once the iframe is loaded
});

chck now, mark it as answer ;) :D

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [`window.setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function. Also instead of constantly polling can't you be notified by the javascript code that changes the `src` property for this change?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but I would try to do it:
You can try and bind a "load" event to the iframe. Once the URL has changed the iframe should fire the load event as the page has been reloaded.